# Attaching string characters to date calculations

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, ssms

I am trying to attach an '*' to the end of a date calculation.

Date_of_birth and Date_of_Activatiion has the same date format YYYY-MM-DD

```
ISNULL([date_of_birth],(DATEADD(YEAR,-[age],[date_of_activation]))) [DOB]
```

The output of this code will be [date_of_birth] OR a calculation for the date of birth based on the person's age and the activation of a product.

How do I attach an '*' to show when the date of birth is calculated?

Here is an attempt I made;

```
ISNULL([date_of_birth],CONCAT(DATEADD(YEAR,-[age],[date_of_activation]),'*','')) [DOB]
```

ERROR;

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I browsed a few other posts but I cannot find a case where they attach the string after a date calculation.

Ideally, the output would look something like; YYYY-MM-DD* when date of birth is null.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. `ISNULL` returns the data type of whatever the first parameter has. `[date_of_birth]` is clearly a Date and time datatype, however, `CONCAT(DATEADD(YEAR,-[age],[date_of_activation]),'*','')` is never going to return a `date`, hence the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ISNULL()` inside `CONCAT()` with *case* expression :

```
SELECT CONCAT(ISNULL([date_of_birth], (DATEADD(YEAR,-[age],[date_of_activation]))),
              CASE WHEN [date_of_birth] IS NULL THEN '*' END
             ) AS [DOB]
```